# Is there ability to use masterpages inside masterpages in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any ability to use masterpages inside masterpages in ASP.NET MVC 5?

I have a site and main layout page in it.
And i have adminka controller with many pages, on any page here i want to add additional menu on site inside firstmasterpage. I am looking an idias how to handle it not using copypaste code in stile of DRY pattern.

Comment: you can use nested layout pages, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor Layout pages are the equivalent to MasterPages in ASP.NET Web Forms and the Web Forms View Engine within ASP.NET MVC. Just as it is possible to nest MasterPages, it is also possible to nest Razor Layout pages.  But you must be attentive during using sections in this case. Check this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcinon/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections/